# tmux status bar path customization with sed

Tags: bash, sed, tmux

On the server I connnect to my home path is like this:`/home/junk1/junk2/user`. I can use the sed command `pwd | sed -e 's|^/\([[:alnum:]]*\)/[[:alpha:]]*/[[:alpha:]]*|/\1|'` to shorten the directory path to this: `/home/user`.

On the tmux status bar I can set the current directory with `set -g status-right '#(pwd)'`. However, because i want to shorten the paths, I tried the above expression by setting:

```
set -g status-right "#(pwd | sed -e 's|^/ ([[:alnum:]]*\)/[[:alpha:]]*/[[:alpha:]]*|/\1|')"
```

This doesn't work. The status bar gets updated with some portion of the text from the sed expression. How can I fix this?

Comment: OFF: `sed 's|\>\(/[^/]*\)\{2\}||'` looks better

Comment: Are you sure to exchange quotes `' / "` ? Where is missed `\ ` before `(` in `s|^/ ([[:alnum`

Comment: @Costas I missed the ``\ `` in the expression while typing here. But the slash is present in my codes. I don't understand your question about the quotes.

Comment: In your sample `set -g status-right '#(pwd)'` but you use `"`. A you sure that isnot a trouble reason?

Comment: If i replace all double quotes by single quotes then nothing gets displayed. If I switch the double and single quotes in the expression, then the entire thing ``/home/junk1/junk2/user`` is displayed and this doesn't change when changing directories.

Comment: Try `set -g status-right '#(pwd | sed "s|\>\(/[^/]*\)\{2\}||")'`